# Varying position of divider between bootstrap grid columns using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am implementing bootstrap grid in my webpage. Now I want to set divider between 2 grid-columns/divs .o achieve that I could have easily used `border-right` property but that would fall short when the web-page is in mobile view `xs or sm`.
Thus I want a view and divider such that when in larger view the columns has a divider cum border-right and when in mobile view it has divider cum-border-right..The attached pictures might tell the story better..

> The desktop view is-

[image: Desktop view]

> And the Mobile view looks like..

[image]

Now I am giving the script that I implemented to obtain this feature-

```
"use strict";

function isBreakpoint( alias ) {
    return $('.device-' + alias).is(':visible');
}

if( isBreakpoint('xs') ) {
  $('.cdiv').css('border-bottom', 'none');
    $('.cdiv').css('border-bottom', '1px dotted black');

}
if( isBreakpoint('sm') || isBreakpoint('md') ||isBreakpoint('lg') ) {
  $('.cdiv').css('border-bottom', 'none');
    $('.cdiv').css('border-right', '1px dotted black');

}


var waitForFinalEvent = function () {
      var b = {};
      return function (c, d, a) {
        a || (a = "I am a banana!");
        b[a] && clearTimeout(b[a]);
        b[a] = setTimeout(c, d);
      };
    }();

var fullDateString = new Date();


$(window).resize(function () {
    waitForFinalEvent(function(){

        if( isBreakpoint('xs') ) {
           $('.cdiv').css('border-right', 'none');
           $('.cdiv').css('border-bottom', '1px solid black');       
        }
      if( isBreakpoint('sm') || isBreakpoint('md') ||isBreakpoint('lg') ) {
        $('.cdiv').css('border-bottom', 'none');
        $('.cdiv').css('border-right', '1px solid black');
      }

    }, 300, fullDateString.getTime());

});
```

**Now the problem is - though I am getting the desired feature-its very inconsistent , meaning- for example the transition between different borders takes a lot of time and show inconsistency, sometimes both the borders come along together or sometime `border-right` is still present though my screen has entered the territory when `border-bottom` should be present**

Any help to figure out the smooth transition between different borders at different dimensions ..

```js
"use strict";
function isBreakpoint( alias ) {
    return $('.device-' + alias).is(':visible');
}

if( isBreakpoint('xs') ) {
  $('.cdiv').css('border-bottom', 'none');
    $('.cdiv').css('border-bottom', '1px dotted black');
  
}
if( isBreakpoint('sm') || isBreakpoint('md') ||isBreakpoint('lg') ) {
  $('.cdiv').css('border-bottom', 'none');
    $('.cdiv').css('border-right', '1px dotted black');
  
}


var waitForFinalEvent = function () {
      var b = {};
      return function (c, d, a) {
        a || (a = "I am a banana!");
        b[a] && clearTimeout(b[a]);
        b[a] = setTimeout(c, d);
      };
    }();

var fullDateString = new Date();


$(window).resize(function () {
    waitForFinalEvent(function(){

        if( isBreakpoint('xs') ) {
           $('.cdiv').css('border-right', 'none');
           $('.cdiv').css('border-bottom', '1px dotted black');       
        }
   if( isBreakpoint('sm') || isBreakpoint('md') ||isBreakpoint('lg') ) {
  $('.cdiv').css('border-bottom', 'none');
  $('.cdiv').css('border-right', '1px dotted black');
   }

    }, 300, fullDateString.getTime());
      
});
```

```css
.cdiv h3{
 color: navy;
}
button{
 margin-top: 10px;
 position: absolute;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 1;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content=="IE=edge"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <title>Q8</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="./q8.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="q8res.js"></script>
</head>
 
<div class="device-xs visible-xs"></div>
<div class="device-sm visible-sm"></div>
<div class="device-md visible-md"></div>
<div class="device-lg visible-lg"></div>
<body>
 <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row" style="padding: 10px;">
   <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12 cdiv">
    <h3>Latest News</h3>
    <p style="margin-bottom: 20px;"> It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum .</p>
    <div class="btdiv" style="margin-top: 10px;"><button class="btn-primary">More</button></div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12 cdiv">
    <h3>Feel free to Communicate</h3>
    <p style="margin-bottom: 20px;"> Donec tellus elit, lobortis ac velit non, scelerisque facilisis quam. Morbi sagittis risus sed pellentesque eleifend. </p>
    <button class="btn-primary">More</button>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
    <h3>Our Facilities</h3>
    <p style="margin-bottom: 20px;"> Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy.</p>
    <button class="btn-primary">More</button>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```